# Отправка фото в анонимный чат телеграм

Tags: python, telebot, чат

Пишу анонимный чат в телеграм, отправка голоса и эмодзи работает,но отправка фото не работает.Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать отправку фото. Ниже код которым я пытаюсь это реализовать.

```py
    @bot.message_handler(content_types='photo')
    def bot_photo(message):
        if message.chat.type == 'private':
            chat_info = db.get_active_chat(message.chat.id)
            if chat_info != False:
                bot.send_photo(chat_info[1], message.photo.file_id)
            else:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '❌ Вы не начали диалог!')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bot.send_photo(chat_info[1], message.photo[-1].file_id)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: А можете дать объяснение почему было важно изменить эту строку?

Comment: Айди полученого фото с наилучшим возможным качеством находится в последнем словаре списка message.photo

Comment: Последний это -1 ?

Comment: Да     .............